# How to set list item icon

Tags: 2010, list-view, file-icons

We have a bunch of SharePoint 2010 lists that use the Icon column type and have a link column that points to a PDF or an online ASPX form. We'd like the icon image to appear at the end of the item's link text, not aligned left or right in its own column. Is this possible? Thanks.

Update: Here's an example of what I'm talking about. Here's how it appears currently:

```
My Column Link Text   |    [icon]
Another Column        |    [icon]
```

Here's how we want it to appear:

```
My Column Link Text [icon]
Another Column [icon]
```

In other words, the two columns would be combined into one. Is this possible?

Comment: I think that only solution is to programmatically build custom column to include both title and icon but that would be huge overkill.

Comment: Thanks, Vedran. Is this possible using computed columns or is that for something else?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx just for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit positions of the columns in the view.

Go to your list -> Modify view -> Change the position of the column "Type" (usually position 1) and put right after the "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" column.

Comment: Thanks, AlexPoint. We've tried that. Please see my update to the question above to see what we're looking for.